# Audio Latency at GamingAnywhere

Tags: audio, video, streaming, video-streaming, audio-streaming

I am establishing GamingAnywhere on a Ubuntu 12.04 Server. The server is running, the only problem is there is a delay on audio while the video is running without any latency.

I am having 2 second latency with the sound. There is no noticeable latency for the video.

The sound latency should be the same for the sound as the video, and I have no noticeable video latency.

What can be the reason?